# Windows BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Earlier today, I was developing an application that restarts itself when it encounters an error. Being stupid, I forgot to ensure that the application was actually exiting before it started a new instance of itself. This lead to the spawning of around 2000 identical processes and made my laptop unusable. I decided to remove the power source and it turned off. When I turned it back on, I was met with the BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO BSOD and can no longer reach the login screen.

Luckily, I have an external HDD with grub2 and multiple Linux distros (including Ubuntu). I booted Ubuntu to download the windows 7 install iso (as it has repair tools) and was able to boot this iso from another USB device. On the installation, I opened repair my computer and used the bootrec program to attempt to recover my windows. This did not work and simply returned claiming that my HDD was of an u recognised format.

After this, I tried to use the bootsect command. This returned with a success message. I rebooted my computer only to find that I could no longer get to the grub boot menu and instead was met by a message saying Missing operation system.

Now I'm screwed and was wondering if anyone could help. I have multiple other available machines.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the computer by selecting "last known good configuration" in the boot options.
If the restart does not fix the problem, the registry damage is too extensive. You must reinstall the OS or use the Emergency Repair Disk (ERD) that you previously created by using the Windows Backup tool.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/hardware/ff559188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I have tried that and I get the same bsod. Thanks for the reply though